# I am trying to install the Infragistics control on azure virtual machine but getting following error

Tags: asp.net, .net, windows, azure, infragistics

Error 1609: an error occurred while applying security settings. ASPNET is not a valid user or group
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are two reasons why you would receive this message.

1. You installed NetAdvantage and you do not have IIS installed.
2. You have IIS installed, but you are missing the ASPNET client.

I suggest you check troubleshooting guide related to the 1609 - ASPNET issue:
http://devcenter.infragistics.com/Support/KnowledgeBaseArticle.aspx?ArticleID=6691

Comment: Thanks you very much Jason